# How to use Unix timestamp to get offset using SimpleConsumer API?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to use [SimpleConsumer example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example).

I modify the offset in the code:

```
long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer,a_topic, a_partition, kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime(), clientName);
```

It works well when I use `kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime()` or `kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime()`. But when I set it to a UNIX TIMESTAMP, it doesn't return the message at that moment.

For example

```
long readOffset = getLastOffset(consumer, a_topic, a_partition, 1439196000000L, clientName);
```

I set the timestamp to 1439196000000L which is 2015/8/10 16:40:0. It however returns a message about one hour before that time.

1. Is it the right way to assign the time stamp? the time stamp should be 13bit, not 10bit, right?
2. I am in China, using Beijing time. Does it matter?
3. Is it possible that Kafka has any parameter to set the time of the cluster?

Comment: Have you read https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell, esp. `--time <Long: timestamp in milliseconds / -1(latest) / -2 (earliest) timestamp; offsets will come before this timestamp, as in getOffsetsBefore  > `?

Comment: @jinhong_lu any luck on this? I am trying to do the same thing.